# How to fix "No module named 'quaternion'" in Python?

Tags: python, import, module, quaternions

I am trying to import the module quaternion into my code to be able to rotate my sensor data. I keep getting the error, 'No module named 'quaternion''.

To install the quaternion module to my computer I used my command prompt and typed

```sh
> conda activate base
> pip install quaternion
```

When I run

```
import quaternion
```

this is the output:

```
(base) C:\Users\erapp\Code>C:/Users/erapp/Anaconda3/python.exe c:/Users/erapp/Code/mbl_mc10/code/sensor_prep_utils.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/erapp/Code/mbl_mc10/code/sensor_prep_utils.py", line 1, in <module>
    import quaternion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quaternion'
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you have 2 versions of python installed then pip install library for one and you might be using other version of python to run in visual studio. Or other thing may be is that conda activate base must have started its own virtual environment where the module quaternion was installed. I would suggest for system wide use  do pip install module on terminal if you are on linux or similar thing on other platform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should solve this by installing the conda package for `quaternion` (available from [conda-forge](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/quaternion)) with `conda install -c conda-forge quaternion`

In your case it looks like you're not using `pip` from your conda environment, which results in installing the package outside this environment. (test with `which pip`)

If you're interested, here are some [guidelines](https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/) on using `pip` with `conda`, and [future evolutions](https://www.anaconda.com/conda-4-6-release/) on interoperability between the two.

Comment: That's what I did, and running `conda list` yields `quaternion                2019.7.23.15.26.49  py36hc8d92b1_0    conda-forge`, but when running `python` and asking for `import quaternion`, I do get ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'quaternion'```

Comment: Then either you should try reinstalling, either you're not calling the right python interpreter.

Comment: Deactivating and reactivating the conda environment fixed it.

Answer (score 7):

Unfortunately — for reasons beyond its maintainer's control — this package has a different name on pypi (which is where pip gets its packages) than it has on conda-forge or when being imported: it's called `numpy-quaternion`.  The easiest way is indeed to use conda, as FabienP suggested.  But if you insist on using pip, you just need to follow the instructions:

```sh
python -m pip install numpy-quaternion
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like using conda to install quaternion working better than using pip on MacOS. Refer to https://quaternion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).